# download svg to png size image

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to have an svg downloaded from my site as a png. Searching I found this code and I must say that everything works. The site is a project that will only be viewed from mobile https://7c81b.wineqrcode.com/ and I would like you to change the size of the downloaded image. Currently the photo is generated based on the size of the svg. Is there any way to get around this? Thanks

```
function downloadSVGAsPNG(e){
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const svg = document.querySelector('#Layer_1');
const base64doc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg.outerHTML)));
const w = parseInt(svg.getAttribute('width'));
const h = parseInt(svg.getAttribute('height'));
const img_to_download = document.createElement('img');
img_to_download.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + base64doc;
console.log(w, h);
img_to_download.onload = function () {
    console.log('img loaded');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', w);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', h);
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(img_to_download,0,0,w,h);
    const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), "download.png");
    e.preventDefault();
    } else {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const my_evt = new MouseEvent('click');
    a.download = 'download.png';
    a.href = dataURL;
    a.dispatchEvent(my_evt);
    }
    //canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
}  
}
const downloadPNG = document.querySelector('#downloadPNG');
if(downloadPNG) { downloadPNG.addEventListener('click', downloadSVGAsPNG);}
```

Comment: this doesn't look like a WordPress question, you should ask generic javascript questions on stackoverflow

Comment: also instead of this you could just save the SVG as a PNG locally and upload/link to the static file, there's no need for javascript here. Also you can pinch to zoom on mobiles, why would users want a blurry version of a chart with text they can't read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const w = parseInt(svg.getAttribute('width'));
const h = parseInt(svg.getAttribute('height'));
```

Change those 2 lines so that `w` and `h` have the desired values.

E.g.

```js
const w = 101;
```

Will make the result 101 pixels wide

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Prepare image in the backend. PHP has libraries for that. GD, or better yet, imagick if you have it installed / can install.
So this is how it should work:
Trigger image download in frontend (javascript). Start AJAX (fetch) call to backend. In the backend use PHP to convert and resize image. Return to javascript as a binary.

It is much more work, but it is much more solid solution. Other than that, you can look into javascript libraries for resizing images, but that would be slower and rely on client capabilities, which might not be sufficient.

Comment: My svg will be edited by users. Through buttons they change the colors and as a result I would like them to download svg to png.

Comment: You can still use method that I described. You should just send edited svg data to backend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data